# Sci-fi cartoon movie about son whose mother becomes a computer

Tags: story-identification, anime, hard-sci-fi

Looking for title of an animated Sci-fi from late 80s early 90s. I vividly remember a scene where a mother turns into a computer run by a large crystal in order to save child. I also recall, though might be mashing up two different movies, the father had left a key to a super weapon embedded in the kids hand. Very similar premise to Titan AE but not the one I'm thinking of.

Might have "Star" or "Space" in title.

Comment: Is it like a gradual transition? Piecemeal replacement? Brain ripped out and put in the computer? Brain download?

Comment: From what I recall it's a download or "life-force" transfer. Follows the "kid is special, mother sacrifices herself to keep him safe" trope. The mother then becomes an AI for the base kind of deal.

Comment: There are tones of this in Neon Genesis, but I don’t think that’s what you’re thinking of.

Comment: No I don't think so. Would had rented it on VHS back when we had to rent the machine (didn't have a VHS at home). From recollection it would have been after Mighty Orbots, that was something else we rented to watch. SO I'm thinking timeframe 1985-87ish. It is a common trope though. Voltron had a similar father is the computer and helps daughter, but genders would be swapped. There was a galactic empire chasing after them, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the cartoon show [Defenders of the Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defenders_of_the_earth)? Flash Gordon fights crime alongside his son (plus other heroes and their respective children), and stores his late wife's consciousness inside a computer.

Comment: You can improve your answer by linking to sources for this

Comment: Looks like I'm mashing up two shows, but the mother in the computer is def this show.